# LSUV init in tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to implement LSUV init as in :

https://github.com/ducha-aiki/LSUVinit
https://github.com/ducha-aiki/LSUV-keras/blob/master/lsuv_init.py

in tensorflow and I encounter some difficulties.
Basically, the algorithm should be something like :

```
    For each layer L do 
        while |Var(Bl) -1| > epsilon
          do forward pass with mini-batch
          calculate Var(Bl)
          Wl = Wl/sqrt(Var(Bl))
        end while
    end for
```

1. Is there any way to iterate over each layer in the network ?
2. How to get the activation for each layer after a single pass ?
3. I was trying to calculate the variance of each layer with tf.nn.moments but this function return a tensor, how to evaluate the value of this tensor ?
4. I am wondering what is better to do : to build a different inference graph for initialization and training phase or to run some "training" in order to initialized the model and load it before the real training .Any advises ?

Comment: Just fill a model["layer_i"] dictionnary with each layer and then call sess.run([model["layer_"+str(i)] for i in [1,...,n]],feed_dict={}) or something similar it will run only one forward and you will get all activations (you can store them in a dictionnary too) disclaimer: I have no idea what LSUV is.

Comment: Considering question 4 you should keep the same graph.

Comment: Considering question 3 just sess.run(tf.nn.moments()) in the same call where you fetched the activations. You may want to use collections.

Comment: Keras seems to have it implemented already.